# A question on bounded gaps in sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let $k$ be a positive integer. Does there always exist an infinite set $S$ of positive integers, such that there is a bounded gap between the $n$-th and the $n+k$-th element of $S$, but the gap between the $n$-th and the $n+k+1$-th element of $S$ is not bounded? By "bounded gap", I mean, no matter how far you go along the number line, you will keep finding members of $S$ less than a fixed distance apart.

Comment: I don't understand your definition of a bounded gap.  I'd have thought that, in the given context, you meant "there exists a constant $M$ such that, for all $n\in \mathbb N$, $|s_{n+k}-s_n|<M$".  But your final statement suggests that you mean something a lot weaker.

Comment: @lulu I in fact mean the weaker statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say infinite set, but then reference an order it sounds like you mean a sequence. So consider the following sequence
$$a_n=\begin{cases}
0 & 2\mid n \\
n & 2\nmid n
\end{cases}$$
That is it is $0$ for even numbers and just $n$ for odd numbers. We see that the bound between the bound between $a_n$ and $a_{n+2}$ is at most $2$, but if you consider a really high even number you have that $a_n=a_{n+2}=0$, but $a_{n+3}=n+3$ which becomes unbounded as $n$ gets really high.

Note: with the comment below on what is meant by an infinite set as what would be a strictly increasing sequence, then the answer is no since if there is a bound between $a_n$ and $a_{n+k}$, say we have that $a_{n+k}-a_n<M$, then $a_{n+2k}-a_n<2M$ by applying the bound two times, but since you are requiring it to be an increasing sequence you must have that $a_n<a_{n+k}<a_{n+k+1}<a_{n+2k}$, so you can conclude that $a_{n+k+1}-a_n<2M$. So you get that this will always be bounded.

Note: with the other comment about injectivity. If you get rid of the strictly increasing condition, but want the sequence to be injective, then the above sequence works if you modify the even terms to be $-n$, so we have that
$$a_n=\begin{cases}
-n & 2\mid n \\
n & 2\nmid n
\end{cases}$$
Since every number and the one that is two away from it has a difference of at most $2$, but if you take an odd and an even (with $n$ really high), then that difference grows unbounded.

Comment: When I say an infinite set $S$, I mean really the injective sequence $s_1, s_2,...$, where $s_1$ is the least element, $s_2$ the second least, etc.

Comment: But your sequence is not injective.

Comment: See the edits to the above post, you can't make it unbounded if you require the sequence to be increasing, but if you just want injective, then I can make it unbounded.